# 301 Redirect with .htaccess and Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect a path on my server to sub domain with the following .htaccess on my Apache server:

```
Redirect 301 /shop test.foobar.com/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I then restart my Apache service but the redirect is ignored. What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to avoid mixing mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) and mod_alias (`Redirect`) directives in the same context. Mod_rewrite will execute first, despite the apparent order of the directives in `.htaccess`.

However, your `Redirect` directive is completely invalid (you are missing a *protocol* from the target URL) - this shouldn't be "ignored"? In fact, I would expect this to break your server with a 500 Internal Server Error - "Redirect to non-URL"!?

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shop$ https://test.foobar.com/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser.

Only change it to a 301 when you are sure it's working OK.

> I then restart my Apache service ...

There's no need to restart Apache if you are only changing `.htaccess`.